# How to run multiple bash command corresponding to each line input from a file?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to run multiple commands in bash whose arguments are each line in a file

e.g.

```
$ cat argsFile.txt
argtype1
argtype2
argtype3
```

And I want to run 3 bash commands corresponding to each line in the file

```
$ python myscript.py argtype1
$ python myscript.py argtype2
$ python myscript.py argtype3
```

How do I do this in 1-2 lines in bash?

Comment: Is there some reason you have to limit yourself to 1-2 lines? The objective with coding (scripting as well) isn't to see how few lines it can be done it, but rather how to write it properly and make it easy to read and maintain. (e.g. don't forget `# comments`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a single liner using `xargs` to run a command line using each line of input file:

```bash
xargs -n 1 python myscript.py < argsFile.txt
```

Note that if input file is very big and you want to run these commands in **parallel** then you can add `-P 0` option of `xargs`:

```bash
xargs -P 0 -n 1 python myscript.py < argsFile.txt
```

Comment: Alright, that wins on shortest and torpedoes my readability comment `:)`

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be sufficiently accomplished by:

```
while read -r args; do <command> "${args}"; done < inputfile
```

So it becomes:

```
while read -r args; do python myscript.py "${args}"; done < argsFile.txt
```

You can write an `echo` right before the command to ensure it's going to run what you want:

```
while read -r args; do echo python myscript.py "${args}"; done < argsFile.txt
python myscript.py argtype1
python myscript.py argtype2
python myscript.py argtype3
```

Comment: Kudos for the `echo` explanation on how to test to ensure the commands are as you need before turning python loose on the system.